# Using CPLEX in C++, how can I efficiently alter the objective function and then resolve the problem?

Tags: cplex, c++, api

I want to solve an optimization problem using the CPLEX API in C++.
After solving the model, I then want to resolve it using a different objective function.

For that purpose, I learned the functions `setLinearCoef(...)` and `setLinearCoefs(...)` exist.

Here's my current code for a small reproducable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>

int main() {

    int benefitOfZ = 7;

    IloEnv env;
    IloModel Model2(env);

    IloNumVarArray Z(env, 5, 0, IloInfinity, ILOFLOAT);

    IloExpr expr_obj2(env);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        expr_obj2 += benefitOfZ * Z[i];
    }
    IloObjective obj2 = (IloMaximize(env, expr_obj2));
    Model2.add(obj2);

    // Constraint 3
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Model2.add(Z[i] <= 2);
    }
  
    IloCplex cplex2(Model2);
    cplex2.solve();

    std::cout << "Objective Value of Model 2: " << cplex2.getObjValue() << std::endl;

    benefitOfZ = 14;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        obj2.setLinearCoef(Z[i], benefitOfZ);
    }
    cplex2.solve();
    std::cout << "Objective Value of Model 2 after change: " << cplex2.getObjValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now this works how I intend it to. But I read in the documentation that `setLinearCoefs(...)` is more efficient than `setLinearCoef(...)`.

I tried changing the code accordingly but I can't get it work without errors.
The main problem is that I don't properly understand how I need to build the objective function so that I can use `setLinearCoefs(...)` afterwards on it.

Does someone know how I could reformulate my code to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, `benefitOfZ` is a scalar constant and `Z[i]` is a scalar variable. To use `setLinearCoefs`, you would make `Z` the first argument, and for the second argument you would need to create an instance of `IloNumArray` containing the new objective coefficients.